# Kendo UI Grid: Hierarchical column header display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, multiple-columns

We need to achieve this type of hierarchical column display for two columns in a particular Kendo UI Grid (using the Razor engine)

[image: column example]

The "Amount Due" header would be above two sub-headers "US $" and "R$" with the proper borders being displayed. Otherwise we'll just have to implement this using two separate column headers.

The row data currently doesn't group the two columns in any way... they're distinct.

EDIT TO ADD: The columns must remain separate, filterable, and sortable.

All help much appreciated,

Chad Lehman
Enterprise IT, 20th Century Fox

Answer (score 1):

I see you tagged "razor" on this, so I assume you are using the MVC version of the grid. But in the web version, you can put HTML directly into the `title` property. Then you can style that code however you want. I am fairly sure you can do the same thing in MVC:

`columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title("<b>Name</b>");`

Here is an example of the web version in the Kendo Dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/Imiq
You can see that I have a `style` tag in the `head`, and I have updated the `title` property on one of the columns.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    div.hdr1 {
        font-weight: bold;
      border-bottom: white 2px solid;
      text-align: center;
    }

    div.hdr2 {
        font-weight: normal;
      border-right: white 2px solid;
      width: 47%;
      float: left;
      height: 14px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    div.hdr3 {
      border: white 0px solid;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                            },
                            pageSize: 20
                        },
                        height: 550,
                        groupable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: true,
                            buttonCount: 5
                        },
                        columns: [{
                            field: "ContactName",
                          title: "<div class='hdr1'>Contact</div><div class='hdr2'>First</div><div class='hdr2 hdr3'>Last</div>",
                            width: 200

                        }, {
                            field: "ContactTitle",
                            title: "Contact Title"
                        }, {
                            field: "CompanyName",
                            title: "Company Name"
                        }, {
                            field: "Country",
                            width: 150
                        }]
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Yes, we're using MVC/Razor for this project. 

I looked at your dojo example, and while the header portion looks right... the requirement is to keep the columns separate, filterable, sortable, etc. In this case, separate columns with no 'super' header is preferable.